# remove inline styles from svg in highcharts

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, highcharts

I have recently started looking at Highcharts for a project and so far I have managed to get the charts I need but the only problem I have is the excessive markup bloat which is created along with the charts. To give an example:

```
<text style="color: white; font-family: Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; position: absolute; fill: white;" x="1288" y="252" zIndex="2">
<tspan style="font-weight: bold;" x="1288">
<text style="color: white; font-family: Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; position: absolute; fill: white;" x="1288" y="452" zIndex="2">
<tspan style="font-weight: bold;" x="1288">
```

This represents just 2 objects in the chart and each time you can see the color, font, position and fill are added as an inline styles...

Having not had too much exposure to SVG, is this a requirement? What I would like to be able to do would be to add a class to the text, say 'hc-txt' then I can set the color, font, position and fill in my CSS file.

e.g.

```
<text class="hc-txt" x="1288" y="252">
<tspan x="1288">
<text class="hc-txt" x="1288" y="452">
<tspan x="1288">
```

Having looked in the src file, I have been able to shorten the prefix from highcharts- to hc- which also helps tidy up the markup a little but changing the way in which these objects are created, am I being over ambitious?

Thanks in advance,

Will.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Highcharts 5 introduces styled mode! 
you can now style the charts using css which will remove the need for all of the inline styles. [Style by CSS - highcharts.com](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-design-and-style/style-by-css)

Answer (score 2):

Adding class attribute to the element should work - please check:

http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/styling.html#StylingWithCSS

and specifically this one:

http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/styling.html#ClassAttribute

Comment: ah, ok... So adding a class is supported using svg, that is good start. Although my problem now is how to get Highcharts to add this class instead of adding the inline style. :-)

Comment: I'm afraid you can't do that with settings alone, you would have to override the Renderer methods. The inline styles are there in order for Highcharts to quickly read the values in both SVG and VML. We are planning a SVG-only version where all styling would be done in classes.

Comment: @Torstein - that will be very useful. I have disabled the charts when SVG is not supported as we only want SVG. I have been removing as much of the style which is added and have been able to use classes in a few places but not all. Thank you for the update.